# How do you find the infinite sum of a series involving a variable?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$$x^{2n}$

wolfram gives: the series to be equal to -$\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}$

How did it get this result?

If i want to find the value of this, I  can't use any tests i know since i havn't yet defined x. so I can't really use comparison or squeeze.

Comment: this is  a geometric series with $r=x^2$ which will only converge for $|x|<1$.

Comment: Can you find the sum of this series in the special case $x=1/3$? That is, can you find $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1/3)^{2n} =\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1/9)^n$? What if $x=-1/2$?  If YES, then ask yourself what special properties of $1/3$ or $-1/2$ did you use that could be used for an arbitrary real number $x$.

Comment: I think the sum should actually be $$ \frac{1}{1-x^2} $$

Comment: ahh, you're right, since your answer is equal to wolfram's answer for $x^2</= 1$

Answer (score 1):

The sum of a geometric series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ar^{n}$$ is $$\frac{a}{1-r}$$ and it converges for $0<r<1$.  Simply replace $r$ with $x^{2}$ for your case.  For $x^{2}<1 \iff 0<x<1$, the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(x^{2})^{n}$$ converges, and interval of convergence is the open interval $(-1,1)$, and the sum is $$\frac{1}{1-x^{2}}$$